# What triggers the eye of the herald opening?

Tags: league-of-legends

When fighting the Herald, it's eye often opens, and hitting it (hitting the herald's back) does a bonus damage.

What triggers that eye opening? Is it every x seconds? or is it at specific checkpoints in it's life?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [League of Legends wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rift_Herald) (emphasis mine),

> After **being in combat for three seconds, the eye on Rift Herald's back
>   will open**. Champion basic attacks against the eye deal (12% of Rift
>   Herald's maximum health) bonus true damage, **causing the eye to close
>   for 10 seconds**, reduced by **2.5 seconds** every time she is struck by a
>   champion's basic attack.

Comment: So if you are 4 chunking down the Herald, you should, seeing this analysis, have the eye pretty much always open. If i can remember right, I don't see that happening. Maybe the wiki hasnt updated after a patch?

Comment: @Fredy31 the animation takes time too

Answer (score 1):

From the [LoL wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Rift_Herald):

> After being in combat for three seconds, the eye on Rift Herald's back will open. Champion basic attacks against the eye deal (12% of Rift Herald's maximum health) bonus true damage, causing the eye to close for 10 seconds, reduced by 2.5 seconds every time she is struck by a champion's basic attack.

Comment: Apologies, looks like I unintentionally formatted my answer almost exactly the same as yours and almost at the same time. I can delete it if necessary.

Comment: @Zodack lol it's fine. It happens sometimes.